# Adding Reference To Owning Object In Ef Core

Tags: asp.net-core, orm, ef-core-2.1

I have two entities: Job and Orderable on our code-first database:

The (extremely simple) models of these two are:

```
class Job 
{
     public Guid Id {get; set;}
     public string JobName {get; set;}
     public List<Orderable> Items {get; set;}
}

class Orderable
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string MaterialNumber {get; set;}
}
```

I wanted to be able to reference the Job from the orderable, so I added a property like so:

```
    public Job OwningObject {get; set;}
```

But when I did the migration, it created a second foreign key for this object.  Now, it seems that if I am getting the Orderables from the Job, it uses key1, but if I am getting the Job from the Orderable, it uses key2.

Within our OnmodelCreating method in our context we have added the following before the key was created, which I thought was required to make it work, but I am not sure if this is potentially causing the issue.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().HasMany(x => x.Items).WithOne();
```

We were able to force the key to reference the proper field with a data annotation of:

```
    [ForeignKey("OwningObjectId1")]
```

But this feels hacky and I don't like it as a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF uses shadow properties to persist the foreign key relationship when no explicit foreign key property is applied. The *best* thing to do is simply have explicit foreign key properties:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(OwningObject)]
public Guid OwningObjectId { get; set; }
public Job OwningObject { get; set; }
```

If you're going to rely on shadow properties, then you need to actually think through what you're doing.

First, when you use `WithOne()`, with no param, it's going to create a shadow property based on the related entity, which is `Job`. As a result, you'll get a column, `JobId`. When you have a reference property, it's going to assume a foreign key column based on the name of that property: `OwningObjectId`. Essentially, the combination of a reference property *and* using `WithOne()` and not referencing that property in the param, actually creates *two* separate one to many relationships. This can be easily corrected by simply telling EF which property to use explicitly:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().HasMany(x => x.Items).WithOne(x => x.OwningObject);
```

Comment: Thank you for the succinct explanation.  I'm about 7 chapters into a really good EF Core book, so I hope that by the time I'm done with it I'll have reconciled the way we've implemented our code first DB with the way we should have.  I'll test updating the foreign key reference annotation and see if it causes data loss.  If it doesn't we will need to roll out that change to all the place we've not had an annotation or fluent Api notation.